MSSQL server mirroring
I have two VM's One is primary and the second is secondary both having sql server with same make and model. I want to make a communicate both VM's to make sure if the primary server goes down the secondary server will up with no loss of data from primary database.
My expectation is, I have two VM's in case of any failure of primary server my secondary server will go live also to sync data between two server.

If your requirement is the redundant copy of your databases on the second server, it is Always On, if you want only ensure "in case of any failure of primary server my secondary server will go live" this is Failover Clustering


if the primary server goes down the secondary server will up with no loss of data from primary database.

Yes, it called mirroring but

You need third server as witness
No loss means synchronous mode so transaction cannot be completed
until it's propagated to secondary server.

Mirroring is deprecated but still supported.
Newer alternative is AlwaysOn Availability group.

Can I do it with SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition.

Yes you can. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#RDBMSHA

Great! Thanks for the answer.
